# CSS - Text : not aligning to the top or wrap

Tags: css, gwt

I'm using the following CSS to align the text at the top of a GWT TextBox and wrap it:

```
.gwt-Label-Wrapped {
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
    vertical-align: top; 
    text-align: left;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

And the `TextBox` is:

```
final TextBox textBoxCSVymValues = new TextBox();
        textBoxCSVymValues.setWidth("600px");
        textBoxCSVymValues.setHeight("200px");
        textBoxCSVymValues.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Wrapped");
        verticalPanel.add(textBoxCSVymValues);
        verticalPanel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(textBoxCSVymValues, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
        verticalPanel.setCellVerticalAlignment(textBoxCSVymValues, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
```

However, the text that I have passed into the `textBoxCSVymValues` is vertically centred and not wrapped. What can I change to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` property will not affect text. It is typically used for images.

Based on your code, it looks like you should be using [TextArea](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextArea.html), not a TextBox.